# Magento order expired in paypal ?? How can re-authorized expired order in magento ?

Tags: magento, paypal, pre-authentication

I am tired to re-authorized order in magento . How can reauthorized order in magento using paypal express checkout . Please describe your answer and solve my problem . Thanks

Comment: In most cases an extension has to be used as I don't recall that Mage has a re-authorization feature in the order itself. Some things to keep in mind. 1. Authorizations expire after the 29 day mark 2. A 1X re-authorization method is available within that period 3. Extensions are used like this one: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-re-authorize-express-checkout.html <-- I am not endorsing, just showing you an extension example

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?